# Slow copy speed from SSD to HDD

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, disk, transfer, copy

I have just installed Ubuntu on my media PC.

It has an SSD as the OS drive, and a 3TB Western Digital HDD from my previous Windows machine, still formatted as NTFS.

When I copy from the WD HDD to the SSD its fast.

But from the SSD to the WD HDD its painfully slow (80 kB/s).

Any help?

Comment: The HDD, is it a SATA connection or usb? Small or large file sizes? Answer by editing your question. Easier for everyone to read.

Comment: Could you please run performance benchmarks on those drives to narrow down the issue? Gnome Disks provides an option for that. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Had a look in the `/etc/fstab` file. Turns out the `sync` option was there for the HDD.

As this is an internal drive and therefore won't abruptly be pulled out I changed the option to `async`.

This has fixed the issue.